# Call an object's member function from a different thread: how to use mutex correctly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

In my class I create a thread, using the `CreateThread(NULL,0,Execute1,this...)` method.

```
DWORD WINAPI Execute1(LPVOID lpParam) {
CoInitialize(NULL);
CVC1Dlg *pdlg=(CVC1Dlg *) lpParam;
```

Then I call the pdlg method from this thread:

```
pdlg->someMethod();
```

What happens, when I call this method from this thread, if this method was called from the main thread at the same time? Should I use some synch method like mutex? And where exactly do I need to call mutex?

Is this correct that I have to use it in the CVC1Dlg method? Something like this:

```
CVC1Dlg ::CVC1Dlg () {
  g_hMutex=CreateMutex(...)
}

void CVC1Dlg ::setStatus(int aStatus) {
  ::WaitForSingleObject(g_hMutex, INFINITE);
  iStatus=aStatus;
  ::ReleaseMutex(g_hMutex);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but if you don't need inter-process synchronization, consider using `CriticalSection` instead of mutex - for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> What happened, when i call this method from this thread, if this method was calling from main thread in same time. Should I use some sync method like mutex? and where exactly I need to call the mutex?

You use mutexes to make state changes atomic, not necessarily to prevent two different threads from accessing the same method at the same time.  Think of it in terms of the data rather than the code.

If a method reads a member variable and writes back a modified value, then you want to make that an atomic operation.

Your example is essentially correct, but it doesn't show that any other method that accesses the `iStatus` member variable should also be protected with a mutex (or critical section).

Answer (score 0):

It depend on what you do in `someMethod`, if it is just for setting an int, then use `std::atomic` or `boost::atomic` for performance, it if is using MFC to access GUI objects or call a non-multithreaded COM object(like an OCX for example), then do not call it from that thread and instead post/send a message to the DLG and in `WindowProc` of that DLG receive the message and do your action, mutexes or critical sections are for the case that you want to change a C++ structure(list, string or my_struct)!

Comment: in fact i use new thread for get the data from socket, and then pass this data next in someFunc(vector<BYTE>)

Comment: @user1746992 OK you pass data and there is no problem in it, important thing is what you do with that data, if you have nothing to do with that data in another thread then there is no need for mutex or something like that but if you do use MFC to for example show that data or you are using a non-multithreaded COM object, then you can't call the function in your thread, instead you should marshal your call to main thread! and simplest way is send/post message to the dialog!